# Book for starting classical guitar player?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, classical-guitar, self-learning

Please excuse my ignorance, I have zero knowledge/experience:

In my mind I have two categories of guitar playing: Strumming (associated with rock) and picking (associated with classical sounding music, jazz, etc.).

I do not want to learn about strumming at all, and in the picking category I do not want to learn any jazz, hip-hop, or modern-sounding music in general; I only want to learn classical-sounding music. Is there a book you would recomend for absolute beginners? I know how to read notes on a score but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't recommend a specific book, I suggest that you look into the beginner and self-instruction guides by [Frederick M. Noad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Noad). Noad authored several instructional guitar books, many focusing on classical guitar playing for beginners.